# Strange results with Grease Pencil Fills, Holdout Materials, a 3D object and Render Transparency

Tags: transparency, grease-pencil

I'm rather new to Blender so apologies if the answer is obvious.

I'm attempting to use a Grease Pencil Fill Material with Holdout to 'cut through' another fill and reveal a 3D object behind the Grease Pencil Object. I'm also attempting to render everything with Alpha using Film > Transparent. The result I'm getting is confusing me.

[image: Render & Viewport]

The pinkish 3D object appears yellow where the Holdout Material is in front of it, and the empty background behind the Holdout appears green. I've tried toggling Z depth on in Passes > Data and the Alpha on the Holdout Material is all the way at 1.

Any idea what's going on? Is the affect I'm looking for not possible?